# Excel to PPT with Do Until

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

[image]

I am doing a macro that will input the NAME into PPT textbox then save as pdf. So how do I loop, or do until my code.

What I want is to continuosly create a new certificate based on my sheet range. The problem is I have blank rows a total of 10 input cell and 9 blank cell because its 1 cell apart. And how do I loop only this code `ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox 13").TextEffect.Text = sh1.Range("114").Text` 
Like if I input 7 names, it will generate 7 pdf with 7 different names on it
Updated Code:

```
Dim fpath As String
Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Automation")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Links")
fpath = "C:\Mondee\01_Automation\Project - Automated Letters\Thank You Award_AUNZ.pptx"
Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
ppApp.Visible = True
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(fpath)
ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox 21").TextEffect.Text = sh1.Range("J111").Value 'do not need to loop
Dim I As Long, LastRow As Long, TbNo As Long
LastRow = 132
I = 114
Do While I <= LastRow
    If sh1.Range("G" & I).Value <> "" Then
    ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox 20").TextEffect.Text = sh1.Range("G" & I).Value 'name that need to loop
    sPath = "C:\Mondee\01_Automation\Project - Automated Letters\"
    sName = sh1.Range("G" & I).Value & ".pdf"
    ppPres.ExportAsFixedFormat sPath & sName, ppFixedFormatTypePDF
    ppPres.Close
    ppApp.Quit
    End If
I = I + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the code and question is not clear on multiple issues.
However assuming

1. TextBox's numbers (for the Names) on the slide 1 is in sequence, starting from "TextBox 13". The TextBox names may be modified from format-selection pane.
2. Names are found in column J of excel sheet Automation starting from row 114.
3. There may be multiple blank rows between two names.

The modified code is tried and working on the assumptions

```
Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
ppApp.Visible = True
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(fpath)
ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox 2").TextEffect.Text = sh1.Range("J111").Value 'do not need to loop

Dim I As Long, LastRow As Long, TbNo As Long
'last excel rows of the names may be ascertained by or directly defined 
LastRow = sh1.Range("J" & sh1.Range("J:J").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

I = 114
TbNo = 13
Do While I <= LastRow
    If sh1.Range("J" & I).Value <> "" Then
    ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox " & TbNo).TextEffect.Text = sh1.Range("J" & I).Value 'name that need to loop
    TbNo = TbNo + 1
    'save to pdf code will be added here
    End If
I = I + 1
Loop
```

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Populating in names do not work, let me reiterate your assumptions
1. TextBox for Name is just the TextBox 13 thats why I want to populate first row to TextBox 13 then save then second row to TextBox 13 then save again....
2. Names are can be found in range G114:H132 as the cells are merged. Maybe the LastRow on your code that I cannot edit can solve.
3. There is only 1 blank per name.
Current code is:
`LastRow = sh1.Range("G" & sh1.Range("G114:H132").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`
`ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox 13").TextEffect.Text = sh1.Range("G" & I).Value`

Comment: I think by now you can make the code work by making modification according to your requirement. If G132 is the last row, simply `Last Row=132` will suffice. Anyway if want to resolve the LastRow, then may use `LastRow = sh1.Range("G" & sh1.Range("G:G").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: The code able to get the 1st name and save as pdf but on the second name, the code stop and having an error on this line `ppPres.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox 20").TextEffect.Text = sh1.Range("G" & I).Value`

Comment: Please share Error no and massage. Moreover keep `ppPres.Close` and 
`ppApp.Quit` out of the loop. It is closing PowerPoint appliction after 1st loop.

Comment: After I take Close and Quit out of the loop. It works perfectly fine, I tried 3 names already. Thanks !! *Cheers*